# How to open a txt file in a mako template？

Tags: python, mako

My tree.txt file is stored in the directory tree. I want to open it in a mako template, and get its context.
Example (should work - but doesn't):

```
% for i in open("tree.txt", "r").read():
    i   
% endfor
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: this error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tree.txt'

Comment: The 'tree.txt' and the mako template file in a simple catdgory

Answer (score 0):

% for i in open("/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/tree.txt", "r").read():

```
${i}
```

% endfor

It's already resolved.When you are opening a file by using a mako template, you must use a absolute path.